# Реализация "rate me" в Android приложениях

Tags: android, google-play

Подскажите правильность действий.
 Как лучше всего реализовать меню "rate me", - пользователь кликает по меню , переходит а маркет и ставит оценку приложению, но...
Как сделать так, чтобы когда юзер поставил оценку , меню или уведомление "поставить оценку" для него больше не появлялось. Можно попробовать использовать sharedpreferences , но если кто то рутом сотрет данные или апп удалится а потом переустановится , то тогда как ?

Comment: отследить, поставил ли пользователь оценку невозможно. Единственное, что возможно - открыть ссылку на приложение в Google Play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, никакого способа проверить наличие оценки приложения от конкретного пользователя нет.
Таким образом, классическая реализация "rate me" через `SharedPreferences` выглядит следующим образом:

1. При первом запуске записываем дату установки
2. При последующих запусках проверяем сколько дней прошло с установки, если, например, прошло 7 дней, то выдаем предложение оценить приложение с вариантами "Оценить", "Не сейчас", "Не напоминать".
3. При выборе "Оценить" - открываем Маркет
4. При выборе "Не сейчас" - обновляем дату в `SharedPreferences` и ждем, например, еще 7 дней
5. При выборе "Не напоминать" - ставим дату в `SharedPreferences` на далекое будущее (дата, от которой никогда не пройдет 7 дней, например, 2100 год)

Как вариант, можно использовать не дату, а количество запусков приложения и предлагать оценить после, например, 10 запусков.

А после переустановки приложения придется мириться с тем, что предложение оценить отобразиться повторно. Однако, если в Вашем приложении есть учетные записи пользователей, флаг наличия оценки можно хранить на Вашем сервере и на основании этого принимать решение - показывать диалог оценки или нет.